# Httponly Cookie header encoded getting with Java HttpClient Apache

Tags: java, cookies, apache-httpclient-4.x, httponly

I use Apache HttpClient to handle http request with cookies. I log requests and my response is not the same like this using Fiddler. [Request in Fiddler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40vhV.png)

Cookie with name _session_id2 and csid have other value in Fiddler and in Java. 
Values in Fiddler have proper value. I have warnings in Java with this two cookies. 
lis 18, 2015 8:09:03 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: csid...

Value in Java of cookie _session_id2 has the same length, but in fact is very different. 
I hope anyone can help me, Thanks !

Comment: You should really provide the necessary details from the linked image in the post - links tend to die and then this won't make any sense to future SO visitors.